# ¿Cómo ingresar un link a una carga de archivos?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive

Encontré un script de Google Apps Script el cual, tu como usuario cargas documentos y al momento de enviarlos se van al Drive deseado, el problema aquí es que solo se permite un documento y necesito que los usuarios me envíen mas de un documento.

Son 4 requisitos que se necesitan para una documentación. Entonces al momento de cargar un archivo necesitaría un link que los re-direccione paso tras paso.
Por ejemplo: se cargo el archivo del paso 1, entonces seguiría la re-dirección del paso 2.
Encontré como re-direccionar a otro link pero no se donde anidarlo ya que no conozco mucho de scripts.

Este es el script de google con el la re-dirección:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}


function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) 
    {
       folder = folders.next();
    } 
    else 
    {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    function doGet() 
    {
       var blob = UiApp.createApplication();

       // Creates a link to your favorite search engine.
       var anchor = app.createAnchor("a link", "http://www.google.com.mx");
       app.add(anchor);
       return app;
   }

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) 
  {
    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [tour] y lee [ask].

Comment: El comentario anterior es porque la pregunta no está del todo clara. Por un lado no mencionas de donde obtuviste el código ni cuáles fueron las líneas de código que agregaste, si se trata de un script en un archivo independiente, o un proyecto incluido en algún tipo de documento de Google o de Google Sites, además de que el código no está completo ya que al menos falta el códgio del archivo form.html. Por otro lado, pareciera que tu pregunta es del tipo "que alguien haga el trabajo por mí" aunque podría asumirse que lo que en realidad estás solicitando es ayuda para aprender programación.

Comment: Te dejo el enlace a un playlist de videos en español de introducción a Google Apps Script -> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuC7OUdarKuYq7VsyKrVPbsRSUrx25YvR

Comment: Por cierto, los nombres de función sólo debe incluirse una vez por proyecto de script. En el script de la pregunta se incluye dos veces doGet.

Comment: Tienes una función que sube un fichero, no podrías modificar el formulario que la alimenta para que pasase los cuatro ficheros y lanzar (bucle) la función el número de veces que sea necesario? Disculpa que lo ponga como respuesta, todavía no puedo poner comentarios.